# Use ffmpeg to add multiple subtitles separately to a video

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle, mkv, srt

I am trying to add multiple languages of subtitles to a video using ffmpeg. I succeeded in adding 1 language, but can't seem to add a second one. 
I use this simple script to add english subtitles to my video.

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -i subs_eng.srt -map 0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec subrip -metadata:s:s:0 language=English "%~n1"_eng.mkv
```

In addition, I run another script to add the Dutch subtitles.

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -i subs_nl.srt -map 0? -vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec subrip -metadata:s:s:1 language=Dutch "%~n1"_nl.mkv
```

But whenever I add the second language, it doesn't seem to do anything. The command terminal shows that ffmpeg is processing the video, but there is only 1 subtitle language available in vlc media player (the first one).

I really want to be able to add it in 2 takes rather than in the same script, as I don't have both languages for all of my video's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without `-map` for the subtitle stream, ffmpeg will select only one subtitle stream from among all inputs.

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -i subs_nl.srt -map 0 -map 1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -c:s:0 copy -c:s:1 subrip -metadata:s:s:1 language=Dutch "%~n1"_nl.mkv
```

I set codec mode for the existing subtitle stream to `copy` and `subrip` for only the new one. This assumes you muxed exactly one subtitle stream earlier.

Comment: I didn't know I  could copy the already existing subtitle stream, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

For a ruby script to mux audio, video, subtitles and chapters, see https://gist.github.com/akostadinov/8197947def1fe61c12a5ffffc615c969

It is easy in fact but verbose if you want to do it properly. You can add subtitles to a file without removing old ones by

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i input.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv
```

`-map x` selects all streams from a file so all streams from both files get into the output file. If you add more input subtitle tracks, you need to supply `-map 2`, `-map 3` and so on. See the very conscious and simple [Map documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).

Now more tricky is if you want to properly label these subtitles. You can add

```
-metadata:s:s:0 language=heb -metadata:s:s:0 handler_name=Hebrew -metadata:s:s:0 title=Hebrew
-metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 handler_name=English -metadata:s:s:1 title=English
```

But you need to know the final mapping which will depend on original files ab/presence of subtitles.

Credits to [eladkarako](https://gist.github.com/kurlov/32cbe841ea9d2b299e15297e54ae8971?permalink_comment_id=4021455#gistcomment-4021455).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create the subtitle file, using different language with one single FFMPEG command:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel "repeat+info" 
-i "file:Intervista.mp4" 
-i "file:Intervista_fr.srt" 
-i "file:Intervista_en.srt" 
-i "file:Intervista_it.srt" 
-c copy 
-map 0 -dn -map "-0:s" -map "-0:d"  
-map "1:0" "-metadata:s:s:0" "language=FR" "-metadata:s:s:0" "handler_name=French"  "-metadata:s:s:0" "title=French" 
-map "2:0" "-metadata:s:s:1" "language=ENG" "-metadata:s:s:1" "handler_name=English" "-metadata:s:s:1" "title=English" 
-map "3:0" "-metadata:s:s:2" "language=ITA" "-metadata:s:s:2" "handler_name=Italiano"  "-metadata:s:s:2" "title=Italiano" 
"file:output.mp4"
```